# Starting a minecraft server using screen doesn't work properly

Tags: debian, ssh, permissions, gnu-screen, minecraft

I'm trying to run a minecraft server on my vServer.

Everything works properly when I start the server like this:

```
java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

But I want the server to run in a screen with a command like this:

```
screen -d -m -S mc-server java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

But everytime I try to start it this way there is just a new screen for a few seconds and then it disapears again. Is something wrong in my command or is there another way to see what happend in this scree before it closed itself?
Or does screen need some special permissions? I use an separate user and all the serverfiles are in the users homedirectory ...

Comment: What do you see if you omit the `-d` option (so it starts in the foreground, not hidden)? Does it work with `nohup`, instead of screen?

Comment: When I leave out `-d` it says "No more PTYs."

Comment: [This answer on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/302235/no-more-ptys-when-trying-to-start-screen) might be relevant.

Comment: `mount devpts /dev/pts -t devpts -o mode=620` leads to:
`mount: devpts already mounted or /dev/pts busy
mount: according to mtab, devpts is already mounted on /dev/pts`

Comment: Maybe you really did run out of PTYs?

Comment: I am not sure if `nohup` is an option ... I have to use somthing similar to `-X stuff "command"` later.

Comment: I suggested `nohup` only for diagnostic purposes. You really should be able to do it with screen.

Comment: Where can I check whether I have enough PTYs and which processes claim them?

Comment: The SuperUser question I linked show how to check how many. I'm not sure how to check who has them, but when you're talking about 4000+ processes `ps -ef` will probably give a clue.

Comment: `# root@vps10343:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr`
`0`
`# root@vps10343:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/max`
`4096`
`# root@vps10343:~# uname -a`
`Linux vps10343.alfahosting-vps.de 2.6.32-028stab101.1 #1 SMP Sun Jun 24 19:50:48 MSD 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
`# root@vps10343:~# grep /dev/pts /proc/mounts`
`devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime 0 0`

Comment: Looks like you do have the same problem: `/proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr` should be *at least* 1 or your shell wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes seems so but how can I change this?

Comment: unmount and remount?

Comment: `/proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr` is still 0 after `umount devpts` and mounting again

Comment: I'm mystified. I suggest you post a new question for the real problem so the right people see it. Don't forget to reference the other question or you'll just get told it's a duplicate. (Although, I'd be tempted to reboot first, just in case.)