# "No more PTYs" when starting screen as non root-user

Tags: debian, gnu-screen, non-root-user, pty

Whenever I try to start a screen-session as a non-root-user I get "No more PTYs." as a response. 
Same command in the same directory as root works properly.

I tried the solution from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/302235/no-more-ptys-when-trying-to-start-screen) post but it won´t change anything:

```
$ ls /dev/pts  
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr
0
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/max
4096
```

Even unmounting and remounting doesn´t help:

```
$ grep /dev/pts /proc/mounts
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime 0 0
$ umount devpts
$ mount devpts /dev/pts -t devpts -o mode=620
```

Related question of mine: [Starting a minecraft server using screen doesn´t work properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239199/starting-a-minecraft-server-using-screen-doesn%C2%B4t-work-properly)

Comment: join the `tty` group

Comment: @mikeserv still the same but `groups` doesn´t display `tty` in root and the other user I want to use ..

Comment: you need write access to `/dev/ptmx`. it should be enough to be in the tty group. if not, `chmod` it, or figure out why.

Comment: It seems that `/dev/ptmx` is not existing: `chmod: cannot access "/dev/ptmx": No such file or directory`

Comment: `/dev/pts/ptmx` then? weird. what system is this? are you using only bsd ptys?

Comment: "Debian 6.0 / Confixx 3.3.9 / 64 bit"    `uname -a` `Linux vps10343.alfahosting-vps.de 2.6.32-028stab101.1 #1 SMP Sun Jun 24 19:50:48 MSD 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux` do you need more information? `/dev/pts/ptmx` same problem ... what are "bsd ptys" I am new to this topic

Comment: same problem? it doesnt exist? bsd ptys are prematched pairs - and w/ a 2.6 kernel you might just be using those. theyre named like `/dev/ptyp1` for the master end and `/dev/ttyp1` for the slave. why is the kernel so old? is it an embedded device like a router or something? do `man pty` if youve got `man` pages.

Comment: It is a 7-days-trial vServer hosted by Alfahosting

Comment: `/dev` contains `pts`(empty), `ptyp0-f`, `tty`, `tty0-9` and `ttyp0-f` which of those should I `chmod 755`?

Comment: well, there you go. youre using bsd ptys and dont have any unix98 ptys at all. probably `screen` can do something with those, but i dont it think it does by default. i would guess you would want to `chown` and `chmod` the slave device you want to use.

Comment: But how do I know which one I am going to use with screen?

Comment: i think you just pick one. i dunno - ive never used them.

Comment: What kind of VM is it?  if it's not a container VM, can you  install a newer kernel on your VM and reboot?  otherwise, maybe look for a different hosting provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very likely you cannot make `screen` use the BSD pseudo terminals because it is compiled to use a specific style of pseudo terminal (never both).  There are two main flavors with variations:

- a function (such as [`openpty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html)) provides the names for the master and slave devices
- the program searches through a list of master/slave pairs for an unused pair

In the latter case, you could do a

```
strings /usr/bin/screen
```

and find something like this: 0123456789abcdef (perhaps longer).  If you do not find that, it is compiled for Unix98 pseudo terminals.

If you *do* find the string, it is possible that `screen` has to run setuid'd, e.g., to **`root`** (so that it can modify the permissions and ownership of the master/slave pairs).

Since the question implies that it works running as **`root`**, it is likely to work for ordinary users after something like

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen
```

Comment: Thanks! `sudo chmod u+s /user/bin/screen` + `sudo chmod 755 /var/run/screen` solved the problem.

Comment: After running `sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen`, trying to run `screen` returns `Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 755.`. (That's where Ragyal probably got it from)